# audio player js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, аудио

Может кто подскажет какой плагин, для аудио плеера где есть ускорение дорожки, и перелистывание вперёд назад на определённое время, вот такого рода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такие функции можно сделать без плагинов.

Comment: а где искать? если есть ссылка, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
audio.ontimeupdate = function(){progress.style.width = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration * 300) + "px"};
progresscontayner.onclick = progress.onclick = function(e){
progress.style.width = (e.pageX - 5) + "px";
audio.currentTime = (e.pageX - 5) / 300 * audio.duration;
}
```

```css
#progresscontayner{
    width: 300px;
    height: 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ccc;
    left: 15px;
}
#progress{
    width: 0px;
    height: 7px;
    background: gold;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<audio id=audio src="http://tolmatux.strana.de/audio/razminka.mp3" controls></audio><br /><br />
<div id=progresscontayner><div id=progress></div></div><br /><br />
Перемотка: 
<button onclick="audio.currentTime=Math.max(audio.currentTime - 15, 0)"> -15с </button>
<button onclick="audio.currentTime=Math.min(audio.currentTime + 15, audio.duration)"> +15с </button><br /><br />
Скорость: 
<button onclick="audio.playbackRate = Math.max(audio.playbackRate - 0.1, 0.1); speed.innerText = audio.playbackRate.toFixed(1)"> -0.1 </button>
<button onclick="audio.playbackRate += 0.1; speed.innerText = audio.playbackRate.toFixed(1)"> +0.1 </button>
<span id=speed>1</span>
```

Comment: Супер,  а как связать временную шкалу с реальным временем аудио, чтоб по клику на шкалу, оно перелистывало, если есть какой пример буду благодарен

Comment: Я добавил в ответ код, который для этого нужен.

Comment: Спасибо, оно только по клику как-то не правильно вычисляет позицию и плеер сразу в конец листает

Comment: дали сайт с таким же плеером, но вытащить код чисто плеера не получается, js сжатый((( https://l-a-b-a.com/blog/priroda-straha-kak-perestat-boyatsya-peremen

Comment: Разобрался почему по клику оно не ту позицию показывало, вместо pageX надо писать offsetX)) теперь только вопрос в выводе времени, не понимаю как вывести часы минуты секунды

Comment: Всё, полностью разобрался, спасибо за наводку, полностью сделал как надо.